# http POST in angular 2 client not working while http GET is working

Tags: angular, http, post, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to do an http `POST` request on angular 2 client (asp.net core 2.0 api server).

At first there was an `415 error (Unsupported Media)`.

When I add an header there is a `response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

Http GET in the same service is working perfectly(without headers).

```html
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  
    // This is working
    getStudents(): Observable <string[]>{
      return this.http.get('https://localhost:44753/api/students', {withCredentials:true})
        .map((res:Response)=> res.Json());
    }
    
    // Return 415
    getStudent(name): Observable <string[]>{
    let data = {
      "name": name
    }
      return this.http.get('https://localhost:44753/api/students', JSON.Stringify(data),          {withCredentials:true})
        .map((res:Response)=> res.Json());
    }
    
    // Return 401
     getStudent2(name): Observable <string[]>{
      let data = {
        "name": name
      }
    
      let headers = new Header();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json);
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers , withCredentials:true });

        return this.http.get('https://localhost:44753/api/students', JSON.Stringify(data),          options)
          .map((res:Response)=> res.Json());
     }
    
 }
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: What server are you using? Are you using the Angular development server or a production server of some kind? If you're using Angular 2, are you able to upgrade to the newer version (5) and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to configure server for CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SearchParams instead of headers in get call

```
    public getStudent = (name: string): Observable<string[]> => {

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('name', name);
    this.options.params = params;

    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44753/api/students', this.options)
        .map(
        data => data.json()
        );
};
```

also double check if you are expecting single string instead of string[]

and decorate by  [HttpGet("{name}")] your WebApi method

```
[HttpGet("{name}")]
public List<string> Students (string name){.....
```